# F# function is good but not when called from main

Tags: f#

I have **F# function 'is_up'** to ping the ip like below which works fine in *FSI REPL*(interactive), giving i.e. true for 8.8.8.8 and false for 8.8.8.1

```
let pingSender = new Ping()
let is_up (t:int) (ip:string) =
    let reply = pingSender.Send(IPAddress.Parse(ip),t)
    reply.Status = IPStatus.Success
```

but not from main. Here I am always getting 'is down'

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let mutable ip = argv.[0];
    if is_up 3 ip then
        printfn "Host %A is up" ip
    else
        printfn "Host %A is down" ip 
    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of your `Ping.Send()` overload is given in milliseconds ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_NetworkInformation_Ping_Send_System_String_System_Int32_)). Google servers are fast, but I doubt they are that fast.

I bet you are getting the reply status as `IPStatus.TimedOut` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipstatus?view=netframework-4.7.2)). Try increasing the timeout value.

Comment: You could make your `is_up` function take a `(timeout : TimeSpan)` parameter or define a `ms` unit of measure and take `int<ms>` to avoid future confusion. See https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/